# Using MAX in a JOIN statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return the max human_hits of distinct domains but have hit a wall. The statement I have pulls back distinct domains with human_hits, but it just grabs the first one, so it's not the max.

I tried adding MAX to the statement and experimenting but only managed to hang the database.

Here's what I have so far...

```
SELECT q.* FROM ( 
    SELECT ah.datestamp, ad.domain, ah.human_hits
    FROM `a_hits_hourly` ah
    INNER JOIN a_saved_domains ad ON ah.domain_id = ad.domain_id  
    WHERE ah.datestamp > 2016070000 AND ah.human_hits > 0
) q 
GROUP BY q.domain
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks

Steve

Comment: What is `human_visits`? Should that be `human_hits`?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. Could you add some sample data and the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
    SELECT ad.domain, MAX(ah.human_hits)
    FROM `a_hits_hourly` ah
    INNER JOIN a_saved_domains ad 
    ON ah.domain_id = ad.domain_id  
    WHERE ah.datestamp > 2016070000 AND ah.human_hits > 0
    GROUP BY ad.domain
```

It should get you the maximum `human_hits` for each `domain`. Or perhaps I'm not sure what you are wanting.

Comment: Thanks Matt! Seems I was overcomplicating things again :)

Comment: If I had a nickle for every time I did that :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to know the other values, like `datestamp`, that correspond to the records of your interest, you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT domain, datestamp, human_hits 
FROM ( 
    SELECT     ah.datestamp,
               ah.human_hits,
               @rn := if (ad.domain = @domain, @rn + 1, 1) rn,
               @domain := ad.domain domain
    FROM       a_hits_hourly ah
    INNER JOIN a_saved_domains ad ON ah.domain_id = ad.domain_id
    WHERE      ah.datestamp > 2016070000
    ORDER BY   ad.domain,
               ah.human_hits DESC
) q 
WHERE rn = 1
```

The inner query sorts the hits in descending order per domain, adding a row count to it that resets at the start of the next domain. The outer query takes only those records that were numbered with a 1.